# Riemann-Roch theorem and divisor of differential forms

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, arithmetic-geometry

I am studying Riemann-Roch theorem but I have some difficulty understanding the concept of divisor of a differential form and the link between differential forms, their divisors and the RRT.
Could you suggest some books to understand this topics!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Rick Miranda's Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces. If you already know the basics about Riemann surfaces and differential forms, you could start from chapter V.

Comment: Another beautiful classic reference is Griffiths's *Introduction to Algebraic Curves*.

Comment: You can look in [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3176487/276986) a meromorphic function $f$ with $n$ poles is a $n$-fold holomorphic map to the Riemann sphere, by topological arguments we know how many branch points it must have, from which we know the number of zeros/poles of $df$ as well as $g df$ for any meromorphic function $g$

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following sections from Otto Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*:

> $\S$9: *Differential Forms*
>
> $\S$16: *The Riemann-Roch Theorem*

The latter section gives a gentle exposition of the link between differential forms and their divisors before discussing RRT. An upside of this book compared to Miranda's is the use of sheaf theoretic language, which I think is best introduced in a concrete context like the theory of Riemann surfaces.